# SQL Join Stored Procedure Does Not Return List In Blazor Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, blazor

Here I have blazor server app, where I have stored procedure `[dbo].[spGetAllChapter]` which return list of chapter name, class name and subject name in SSMS.

To call this stored procedure `[dbo].[spGetAllChapter]` I have used `_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw()`.

Now, the problem is that on calling stored procedure it does not return list instead it shows -1 value, but on executing same stored procedure in SSMS returns list.

Below is my stored procedure

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAllChapter]
    AS
 BEGIN

SELECT CH.ChapterId
     , CH.ChapterName
     , SC.ClassName
     , S.SubjectName 
  FROM [dbo].[Chapter] AS CH
  JOIN [dbo].[SchoolClass] AS SC 
    ON CH.SchoolClassId= SC.SchoolClassId
  JOIN [dbo].[Subject] AS S 
    ON CH.SubjectId = S.SubjectId

   END
```

Below is how I have called stored procedure

```cs
public eLearningDBContext _dbContext = new eLearningDBContext();    

//getChapterList is -1 instead of returning list from procedure
var getChapterList = _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"EXEC dbo.spGetAllChapter");
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [ExecuteSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw?view=efcore-5.0) say that the function:

```
Executes the given SQL against the database and returns the number of rows affected.
```

Note that it doesn't return the data, but the number of rows affected. Perhaps what you're looking for is [FromSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

Alternatively, you don't need a stored procedure to accomplish what you want; you can simply project the columns you want in a regular EF query, like:

```
_dbContext.Chapters.Select(ch => new 
{ 
    ChapterId = ch.ChapterId, 
    ChapterName = ch.ChapterName, 
    ClassName = ch.SchoolClass.ClassName, 
    SubjectName = ch.Subject.SubjectName
}).ToList()
```

This will give you a list of anonymous objects with the fields you want, but you could also create a named type (Like `ChapterAbstract` or something) and project to that instead.

Comment: FromSqlRaw requires specific database table such as _dbContext.Chapter.FromSqlRaw() but mine query is join of three tables which returns data form these three tables not.

Comment: Ah, I see, you're not returning a collection of Entities. Why aren't you just projecting the fields you want, instead of relying on a stored procedure to do it for you? Something like `_dbContext.Chapters.Select(ch => new { Id = ch.ChapterId, Name = ch.ChapterName, ClassName = ch.SchoolClass.Name, SubjectName = ch.Subject.SubjectName}).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

If the context was created DB first,  you can update the DataModel via the Wizard to include Stored Procedures and Functions.  Then you can call the SP directly from the context

_dbcontext.spGetAllChapter();

Comment: Have you tried _dbContext.Database.FromSqlRaw<Chapter>("EXEC dbo.spGetAllChapter").ToListAsync()

Answer (score 0):

I some how solved by making this helper class

```
public static class SQLHelper
{
    public static List<T> RawSqlQuery<T>(string query, Func<DbDataReader, T> function)
    {
        using (var context = new eLearningDBContext())
        {
            using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = query;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                context.Database.OpenConnection();

                using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var entities = new List<T>();

                    while (result.Read())
                    {
                        entities.Add(function(result));
                    }
                    return entities;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
var list = SQLHelper.RawSqlQuery($"EXEC dbo.spGetAllChapter", 
x => new ChapterVM { 
                    ChapterId = (int)x[0],                                                                                                 
                    ChapterName = (string)x[1],                                                                                             
                    ClassName = (string)x[2],                                                                                             
                    SubjectName = (string)x[3]                                                                                            
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: You could avoid all of this if you project directly into your ChapterVM object as I showed in my answer.